# Android app freezes on Android Nougat

Tags: android, freeze, android-7.0-nougat

I have an app that runs perfecly on Android < 7 (marshmallow included), but when it comes to Android 7, after I log in on it, it freezes. It is not happening in other devices and is happening in 2 Nougat devices. App launch fine but when it has to load "a lot" (not a lot really) info, it freezes completly (please see my ). It doesn't happen using the simulator.

What I want to archive at that point is lo load a bunch of images from an URL into a ListView. Also, there is a Google Map component loading in a non yet visible fragment

PERMISSIONS (asked at the begining of the app)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

DEPENDENCIES

```
compile 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.2'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.28.0'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.2'
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.1.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.1.1'
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.1@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
```

GRADLE CONFIGS

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 25
```

MEMORY HISTORY

[CPU,MEMORY and NETWORK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zy6bw.png)

[RED LINE INDICATES THE LOGIN EVENT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rweC1.png)

NOTE: AS does not throw any error when it freezes, so I have not clue of what is going on. If you request more info please ask